# Publish Post on facebook wall with any authenticated user using C#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using  ImpactWorks.FBGraph dll to Post on facebook wall using C#.

I have created App using my xyz@gmail.com id and get AppId and Secret
 key

```
facebook.AppID = "51312xxxxxxxxx";
facebook.Secret = "66e76e49be4e92390fxxxxxxxxx";
```

Its works fine when i loggin with user (xyz@gmail.com)  under which i
 have created App

But when i try to loggin with different facebook account it gives me 
 403 (Forbidden) error.

Comment: Hi Sagar, This is because the only Authenticated user is allowed.

Comment: Yes i Do same, 1. Authenticate user using auth.FacebookAuth() 2. Go to callback url after authenticated  3. get Access token  4. publish to wall. this works with user using which i have created app but if user try to login with their owen fb id then it gives above error

Answer (score 0):

```
Get Solution using aspsnippets.facebookapi.dll. 

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FaceBookConnect.API_Key = "<Your API KEY>";
    FaceBookConnect.API_Secret = "<Your API SECRET>";

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
        {
            ViewState["Code"] = code;
            pnlPost.Enabled = true;
            btnAuthorize.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}

protected void Authorize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FaceBookConnect.Authorize("publish_actions", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}

protected void Post(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    data.Add("link", "http://www.aspsnippets.com");
    data.Add("picture", "http://www.aspsnippets.com/images/Blue/Logo.png");
    data.Add("caption", "ASP Snippets");
    data.Add("name", "ASP Snippets");
    data.Add("message", "I like ASP Snippets");
    FaceBookConnect.Post(ViewState["Code"].ToString(), "me/feed", data);
}
```